# Is the set $S=\left\{\left(z_1,z_2\right)\in \mathbb C\times \mathbb C:z_1^2+z_2^2=1\right\}.$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, metric-spaces

Consider the set $$S=\left\{\left(z_1,z_2\right)\in \mathbb C\times \mathbb C:z_1^2+z_2^2=1\right\}.$$

Is this set compact in $\mathbb C^2$ ?

As $\mathbb C^2$ is a finite dimensional space so a subset of it is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

But $z_1^2+z_2^2=1$ gives $(x_1^2+x_2^2)-(y_1^2+y_2^2)=1$ and $x_1y_1+x_2y_2=0$ , where $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$.

But from here how I can show that the set is closed and bounded ?

Comment: Hint:  You can't show it's bounded.  Reasons why: See the other people's hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider all pairs of the form $(n, i\sqrt{n^2-1})$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The set of such pairs is contained in the given set.

But is this set bounded?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the curve $z: \mathbb{R} \to S$ defined by $z(t) := (\cosh t, i \sinh t)$.

Comment: Clearly the map is continuous..But $\mathbb R$ is not compact

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean?

Comment: The image of the curve is contained in $S$ but is unbounded (as, e.g., the component function $t \mapsto \cosh t$ is unbounded), hence $S$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $w$ is any complex number with real part $1/2$, then $w + \overline w = 1$.